# Get a vector of all edges ids

Tags: c++, igraph

In `igraph`'s c/c++ library, I am trying to write a function which returns a random edge of a `graph`. The intention is to write a larger function which "visits" a random edge at each time step, and stops when all edges have been visited. At each some visit, some external code is being executed.

In order to write such a function, I need to be able to first receive a list / vector / whatever containing all `eid`'s of the edges of `graph`. In the manual I only saw `igraph_get_eids`, which returns a list of edges ids either along a path, or with respect to a vector of vertex pairs.

Of course, I can manually create a vector of all vertex pairs and use it as an input to the above mentioned function, but that seems like an overkill, and probably a more direct (and efficient?) solution it out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

igraph's edge IDs are always consecutive integers from zero to `igraph_ecount(graph)-1` (inclusive), so you can simply generate a random integer from this range to draw a random edge from the graph.

Quoting the [igraph manual](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Basic.html#idm470951454304):

> The igraph graphs are multisets of ordered (if directed) or unordered (if undirected) labeled pairs. The labels of the pairs plus the number of vertices always starts with zero and ends with the number of edges minus one.

Comment: Great, thanks! Could you provide a reference to that?